# ItemClick event on part of GridView

Tags: c#, windows-runtime, windows-store-apps, winrt-xaml

I have a collection of objects that I want to bind to my Xaml (using a GridView at the moment). I don't know if a GridView is the best tool for what I want to achieve.

This is roughly my current DataTemplate:

[image: data template]

I need a clicked/tapped trigger on Grid1. But when I use this template with a GridView, the ItemClick event will get triggered on the complete template - which is correct of course. How can I set an click event on Grid1? Can I add this event in my DataTemplate declaration?

That's basically the xaml for my GridView:

```
<GridView x:Name="RoomsGridView"
                    VerticalAlignment="Top"
                    ItemsSource="{Binding Rooms}"
                    ItemTemplate="{StaticResource RoomTemplate}"
                    SelectionMode="None"
                    IsSwipeEnabled="false" 
                    IsItemClickEnabled="True"
                    ItemClick="RoomsGridView_ItemClick" Padding="0">
                        <GridView.ItemsPanel>
                            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal"/>
                            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                        </GridView.ItemsPanel>                            
                    </GridView>
```

**Edit**: I've found [this sample](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/Command-binding-inside-3cef5eea) but this seems only to work with Buttons!?

Answer (score 1):

In the code you posted above you've told to `GridView` to capture item clicks via `IsItemClickEnabled="True"`. You cannot have that option enabled if you want to be able to click on elements inside the `DataTemplate`.

I would suggest that you disable `IsItemClickEnabled` and instead add a click handler to your Grid1. Even better would be to substitute your `Grid1` with a button that has custom styling. This would further allow you to bind the button to a command that you can control from your view model.

Comment: Hi Kasper, I added a "Tapped" event to Grid1 in my Datatemplate, but how can I access this event in my view model?

Edit: Seems like you just can't "easily" use events in Datatemplates if you have them in your StandardStyles file like I did. I now have the datatemplate locally in the page resources and any events are working now. More information about this issue: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/3e6ef7ea-d9b9-4219-8df4-f3355a1d2b5c/windows-81-datatemplate-in-xaml-resource-file-button-click-event-is-not-called?forum=winappswithcsharp

Comment: I would suggest that you look into using Commands as much as possible. These are easy to use in your view models, and they do not restrict your data templates in any way.

Comment: Ok I will dig into Commands. :) But just to be sure: Is it possible to use commands with the "Tapped" event of a Grid or can you use commands only with the `Command` property of a button? It is just not clear to me how to use them with a tapped event.

Comment: It is not possible. You can work around this using attached properties. Creating your own attached property for grid tapped is rather simple .